# Unexpected regex behavior in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have the following regex expression to validate emails `VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i`

I have also the following test function

```
test "valid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post users_path, params: { user: { first_name: "John",
                                         last_name: "Doe",
                                         email: "john@doe.com",
                                         password: "foobar123",
                                         password_confirmation: "foobar123" } }
    end
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert is_logged_in?
end
```

Yet, the test **fails** only when the email is set to `john@doe.com`
Every single other mail of the same format works. I can't see why. 
Moreover, when I try to manually sign up, the `john@doe.com` address works perfectly fine.

Here's the log message when testing with `john@doe.com`

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 5405
Started with run options --seed 28654

 FAIL["test_valid_signup_information", UsersSignupTest, 1.127243652001198]
 test_valid_signup_information#UsersSignupTest (1.13s)
        "User.count" didn't change by 1.
        Expected: 2
          Actual: 1
        test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:19:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'

  20/20: [=============================================================================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.14680s
```

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe your test method registers the user in a place where that user already exists and doesn't raise usercount.

Comment: @linden2015 Really unlikely. How can I check the database for every single environments (prod, test, dev?) Thanks

Comment: I don't think your regex is the problem: http://rubular.com/r/SC4XTmOwoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is fine, you can check it by doing in terminal:

```
> 'john@doe.com' =~ /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
=> 0
```

The failure only says the number of users didn't change. So it could be anything really. After running your tests open console with `rails c test` and try to create the failed user manually. You will see why it doesn't get created in your test environment.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to reset my database in every single environment. When I launch the rails console, `User.count` returns 0 for **development** and **test** environment. Yet, when I launch the test, I get the same error `"User.count" didn't change by 1.
        Expected: 2
          Actual: 1
` 
How is possible to have 1 record although in the console, it says 0?

Comment: Yes, it was because of a fixture used in another test! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your regex pattern isn't so great.

- It matches: `.@..com`
- It doesn't match: `a_b@d_e.com`
- If you put the `-` at the end or beginning of the character class, then you don't need to escape it. `[\w+.-]`
- For readability: `^` and `$` are far more commonly used.

Email pattern matching is a hard problem. I suggest googling it instead of coming up with your own pattern. Or make the pattern only catch basic errors and emailing the address will tell you if it's valid or not.

Also, your email pattern should have it's own test, to isolate it's proper working. Then when you test a signup method you're only testing the code belonging to that.

Comment: Do note, that `^` and `$` are **not** the same thing as `\A` and `\z`. `^` matches the start of a line, while `\A` matches the start of a string and `$` matches the end of a line, while `\z` matches the end of the string

Comment: Right. Absolute ends. I suppose if you run a `find(pattern)` call, that `BAD DATA \n VALID EMAIL` might get through.